# Combining two SQL Server log tables into a third activity log table

Tags: python, sql-server

State_Log_Table

| EmployeeID | Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | time1 | 2 |
| 001 | time2 | 1 |
| 002 | time3 | 2 |

Item_Log_Table

| Time | AssetID |
| --- | --- |
| time1 | 123 |
| time1 | 456 |
| time2 | 123 |
| time2 | 678 |
| time3 | 891 |

Resultant Table 3 (Event_Log_Table)

| EmployeeID | Time | AssetID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | time1 | 123 | 2 |
| 001 | time1 | 456 | 2 |
| 001 | time2 | 123 | 1 |
| 001 | time2 | 678 | 1 |
| 002 | time3 | 891 | 2 |

I'm new to SQL and looked into JOIN and UNION statements but had no luck. I'm executing these queries in python. Can this be done with a single query?

this is what I have tried so far:

```
    Event_Log_Table (EMPLOYEEID,TIME ASSETID, STATUS)
    SELECT
    State_Log_Table.EMPLOYEEID,State_Log_Table.TIME,State_Log_Table.STATUS
    FROM
    State_Log_Table
    INNER JOIN Item_Log_Table
    ON 
    State_Log_Table.TIME = Item_Log_Table.TIME  
                                '''
```

Comment: *"I'm executing these queries in python."* What statements, you didn't include any in the question. What about them didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
                     ```INSERT INTO 
                             Event_Log_Table (EMPLOYEEID,TIMESTAMP, ASSETID, STATUS)
                             SELECT
                             State_Log_Table.EMPLOYEEID, State_Log_Table.TIMESTAMP,Item_Log_Table.AssetID, State_Log_Table.STATUS
                             FROM
                             State_Log_Table
                             FULL OUTER JOIN Item_Log_Table
                             ON 
                             State_Log_Table.TIMESTAMP = Item_Log_Table.TIMESTAMP;
                            ```
````